# How to do multi-key group-by json transformations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to transform a flat json schema (the result of a MySQL query) into a hierarchical json structure with two keys. I have a working solution, using itertools groupby, but I have more transformations to code (some more complicated than this) and I'm looking for a better way to do this in Python (I'm using 3.7). Maybe I'm overlooking some basic operators in Python that will reduce my lines of code, or maybe there's a better library out there. I've read about pandas which has groupby operations but its focus is on data analysis and not data transformations like this. In Node.js I used [jsonata](https://docs.jsonata.org/overview.html), so I'm wondering if a better library exists in python for json transformations.

To clarify: I want to improve my development efficiency; I am not concerned about run-time efficiency since my datasets are small.

The sample input is shown in the code sample below, and the output needs to look like the following (2 levels of group-by and rename the elements):

```
{'researchSubTypeToResolutionCodes': [
  {'researchSubTypeCode': None, 'resolutionTypes': [
    {'resolutionCode': 999991, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [99992, 99993]},
    {'resolutionCode': 999995, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [99996]}
    ]
  },
  {'researchSubTypeCode': 33533, 'resolutionTypes': [
    {'resolutionCode': 33726, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [33730, 33731, 33732, 33774]},
    {'resolutionCode': 33727, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [33730, 33731]}
    ]
  },
  {'researchSubTypeCode': 33534, 'resolutionTypes': [
    {'resolutionCode': 33726, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [33730]}
    ]
  }
]}
```

Here is the working code which gives the output I need using itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def mapResearchSubTypeToResolutionCodesToSchema(qryResult):
    groupByRschSubTypeDict = {}
    grouper = itemgetter("rsch_sub_typ_cd","resl_cd")
    for key, grp in groupby(qryResult, grouper):
        key_dict = dict(zip(["rsch_sub_typ_cd","resl_cd"], key))
        rschSubTyp = key_dict["rsch_sub_typ_cd"]
        reslSubTypCds = []
        for itm in grp:
            reslSubTypCds.append(itm["sub_resl_cd"])
        resolutionType = {
            "resolutionCode": key_dict["resl_cd"],
            "resolutionSubTypeCodes": reslSubTypCds
        }
        # Add to resolutionTypes list if already there, or create new one
        researchSubTypeCode_resolutionTypes = groupByRschSubTypeDict.get(rschSubTyp)
        if not researchSubTypeCode_resolutionTypes:
            researchSubTypeCode_resolutionTypes = []
            groupByRschSubTypeDict[rschSubTyp] = researchSubTypeCode_resolutionTypes
        researchSubTypeCode_resolutionTypes.append(resolutionType)

    finalResult = _transformToFinalSchema(groupByRschSubTypeDict)
    return finalResult

def _transformToFinalSchema(groupByRschSubTypeDict):
    researchSubTypeToResolutionCodesList = []
    for k,v in groupByRschSubTypeDict.items():
        newItem = {
            "researchSubTypeCode": k,
            "resolutionTypes": v
        }
        researchSubTypeToResolutionCodesList.append(newItem)

    finalResult = {
        "researchSubTypeToResolutionCodes": researchSubTypeToResolutionCodesList
    }
    return finalResult

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TEST_QRY_DATA = [
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": None, "resl_cd": 999991, "sub_resl_cd": 99992},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": None, "resl_cd": 999991, "sub_resl_cd": 99993},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": None, "resl_cd": 999995, "sub_resl_cd": 99996},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33533, "resl_cd": 33726, "sub_resl_cd": 33730},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33533, "resl_cd": 33726, "sub_resl_cd": 33731},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33533, "resl_cd": 33726, "sub_resl_cd": 33732},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33533, "resl_cd": 33726, "sub_resl_cd": 33774},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33533, "resl_cd": 33727, "sub_resl_cd": 33730},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33533, "resl_cd": 33727, "sub_resl_cd": 33731},
        {"rsch_sub_typ_cd": 33534, "resl_cd": 33726, "sub_resl_cd": 33730}
    ]
    result = mapResearchSubTypeToResolutionCodesToSchema(TEST_QRY_DATA)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me two steps, but a lot fewer lines and this should be conceptually easier to read through.

First lets just get the numbers we want. This is basically a `groupby` function. 
To have a better understanding of how it works add a `print` statement at the end of the for loop such as `print(temp_dic)`.

```
temp_dic = dict()
for entry in TEST_QRY_DATA:
    if entry["rsch_sub_typ_cd"] not in temp_dic:
        temp_dic[entry["rsch_sub_typ_cd"]] = dict()
    if entry["resl_cd"] in temp_dic[entry["rsch_sub_typ_cd"]]:
        temp_dic[entry["rsch_sub_typ_cd"]][entry["resl_cd"]].append(entry["sub_resl_cd"])
    else:
        temp_dic[entry["rsch_sub_typ_cd"]][entry["resl_cd"]] = [entry["sub_resl_cd"]]
print(temp_dic)
```

**Output:**

```
{
  None: {999991: [99992, 99993], 999995: [99996]}, 
  33533: {33726: [33730, 33731, 33732, 33774], 33727: [33730, 33731]}, 
  33534: {33726: [33730]}
}
```

Now we can add the desired tags:

```
final_dict = {'researchSubTypeToResolutionCodes': []}
for researchSubTypeCode, dic in temp_dic.items():
    temp_list = [{'resolutionCode': key, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': val} for key, val in dic.items()]
    temp_dic = {'researchSubTypeCode': researchSubTypeCode, 'resolutionTypes': temp_list}
    final_dict['researchSubTypeToResolutionCodes'].append(temp_dic)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(final_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'researchSubTypeToResolutionCodes': [
    {'researchSubTypeCode': None, 'resolutionTypes': [{'resolutionCode': 999991, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [99992, 99993]}, {'resolutionCode': 999995, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [99996]}]}, 
    {'researchSubTypeCode': 33533, 'resolutionTypes': [{'resolutionCode': 33726, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [33730, 33731, 33732, 33774]}, {'resolutionCode': 33727, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [33730, 33731]}]}, 
    {'researchSubTypeCode': 33534, 'resolutionTypes': [{'resolutionCode': 33726, 'resolutionSubTypeCodes': [33730]}]}
]}
```

You may be able to implement a more dynamic & recursive solution using an `OrderedDict` and `defaultdict` with this [example](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2014/10/example-using-groupby-and-defaultdict-do-same-task/) but it would take some time to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've upvoted your answer because it is definitely an improvement over my code. I'm still holding out hope for a good json transformation library that can do this sort of thing with a lot less code though...

Comment: Someone good at pandas could probably help you by turning the list of dicts into a `DataFrame` then doing a `groupby` but pandas is a big package.